# Ada - where is Verbosity_Desired defined?

Tags: exception, ada

I am looking at [this example](https://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/~andy/lrm95/11_04_02.htm) of exception handling in Ada.

What do I need to `with` for `Verbosity_Desired`?

```
   with Ada.Text_IO;
   with Ada.Exceptions;
   with File_System; use File_System;
   use Ada;
   procedure Main is
   begin
       ... -- call operations in File_System
   exception
       when End_Of_File =>
           Close(Some_File);
       when Not_Found_Error : File_Not_Found =>
           Text_IO.Put_Line(Exceptions.Exception_Message(Not_Found_Error));
       when The_Error : others =>
           Text_IO.Put_Line("Unknown error:");
           if Verbosity_Desired then
               Text_IO.Put_Line(Exceptions.Exception_Information(The_Error));
           else
               Text_IO.Put_Line(Exceptions.Exception_Name(The_Error));
               Text_IO.Put_Line(Exceptions.Exception_Message(The_Error));
           end if;
           raise;
   end Main;
```

Comment: "What do I need to with for Verbosity_Desired?"  is not a well formed sentence to me.  Could you rephrase it?  The examples seem to come from Ada LRM with no further elaboration.  So what is your question?

Comment: I meant, do I have to `with XXX;` and what is `XXX`.   How can I build this (after I add some code where it says "... -- call operations in File_System")?

Comment: Somewhere there is defined  Verbosity_Desired : Boolean; in main??  All you need to do is set it to True or False as your desire.

Comment: In the current LRM this is [ARM 11.4.3(10)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-11-4-3.html#p10). [ada-auth.org](http://www.ada-auth.org/) is the best place to look for Ada standards etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like you don't need to `with` anything ... this is probably just for show only and perhaps `Verbosity_Desired` is a boolean you could define yourself.

This example from the LRM is about exceptions and how to get information about them, so it's probably just demonstrating that you can get more verbosity by using `Exceptions.Exception_Information`.

Comment: I will accept that as the answer. I was wondering if it is an Ada system global or something. I am just surprised & disappointed at seeing non-compiling code in a test book :-(

Comment: OK, but `Some_File` isn’t declared in the example either. You have to draw the line somewhere!

Comment: @Mawg what test book? it is standard. And that code is there for illustration purposes only on exception handling.